# Up and Down arrow Button in Windows forms C# visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, winforms

enter image description here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BytBz.jpg)

Hello, Everyone I am trying to figure out a way to make the Exact replica of windows calculator, as a part of my C# learning assignment, I would like to know if there is any direct button in the tool box or any alternative way to get the up and down arrow , which will be used to move in the history of events entered by the user . which will be useful for him to recheck or edit easily. this question is totally related to windows forms UI (design)

Comment: This can be implemented.. Create a UserControl or derive from Button and paint your button how it should look like and how it should act like. There are tons of tutorials how to do so. But I can tell you this is a lot of detail work. I would not do it. Look for existing Windows Forms controls. There are many out there. Or simplify it with existing controls.

Comment: Are you doing this in Windows Forms, in WPF, in something else?  Before you worry about an "Exact replica", get a working version running - for example, you could use `A` or circumflex (`^`) for the up arrow and a `v` as the down arrow, and just make a button with some text (the `^` or `v`) to fill the bill for now

Comment: [Arrow Symbols](https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/arrow-symbols/)

Comment: Thanks a ton , all inputs are valid , fits the purpose and most wonderful thing is I got it working

Answer (score 1):

You can use unicode triangles in the button's text property : ▲ ▼ and make the font bigger so that they're more visible, you can grab the triangles here: https://www.alt-codes.net/triangle-symbols.

If you want the exact same shape you'd have to make the image yourself in paint or just use snipping tool to save the arrows from your attached image. This can be set in the button's image property, remember to clear the text if you're using images.

Both can be set by right clicking the button in the designer and selecting properties.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do that would be to subscribe to a `KeyPress` or `KeyUp` or `KeyDown` event of the control and check if the pressed key is `up` or `down` key and then run your logic.

this documentation might be helpful:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

I have grabbed out my very very old project and want to show you my implementation of a button that supports long press. It is quite a mess to only paint it but to get an idea:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Teronis.Windows.Forms
{
    public class TLongClickButton : Button
    {
        const int DEFAULT_LONG_CLICK_TIMER_TIME = 500; // milliseconds
        const int DEFAULT_LONG_CLICK_TIMER_INTEVALL = 100; // milliseconds

        /// <summary>
        /// A static method for painting in OnPaint.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="btn"></param>
        /// <param name="padding"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Bitmap GetBitmap(Button btn, int padding = 2)
        {
            return new Bitmap(btn.ClientSize.Width - padding * 2, btn.ClientSize.Height - padding * 2);
        }

        public int LongClickTimerTime { get; set; } = DEFAULT_LONG_CLICK_TIMER_TIME;
        public int LongClickTimerIntervall { get; set; } = DEFAULT_LONG_CLICK_TIMER_INTEVALL;

        public bool LongClickSupport { get; set; } = false;
        public EButtonDrawing ButtonDrawing { get; set; } = EButtonDrawing.Close;

        public event EventHandler LongClick;
        public event EventHandler ShortClick;

        Bitmap bitmap;
        Timer longClickTimer;
        int milliseconds;
        int padding = 2; // listbox border
        bool isLongClick;
        bool isMouseDown;
        bool isLongClicking;
        int activeLongClickTimerTime;
        Size clientSize = Size.Empty;

        public TLongClickButton()
        {
            Paint += TLongClickButton_Paint;
            longClickTimer = new Timer();
            longClickTimer.Tick += LongClickTimer_Tick;
        }

        private void TLongClickButton_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ClientSize.Width != clientSize.Width || ClientSize.Height != clientSize.Height) {
                clientSize = ClientSize;
                bitmap = GetBitmap(this, padding);
            }
        }

        private void startTimer()
        {
            activeLongClickTimerTime = LongClickTimerTime;
            longClickTimer.Interval = LongClickTimerIntervall;
            longClickTimer.Start();
        }

        private void LongClickTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (milliseconds < activeLongClickTimerTime)
                milliseconds += longClickTimer.Interval;
            else
                isLongClick = true;
            //
            Invalidate();
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg >= 0x0204 && m.Msg <= 0x020D)
                return;
            else
                base.WndProc(ref m);
        }

        //protected override void OnClientSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
        //{
        //  bitmap = GetBitmap(this, padding);
        //  base.OnClientSizeChanged(e);
        //}

        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs mevent)
        {
            if (LongClickSupport && mevent.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
                isMouseDown = true;
                isLongClicking = true;
                startTimer();
            }
            //
            base.OnMouseDown(mevent);
        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs mevent)
        {
            if (mevent.Button.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Left)) {
                var isInClientArea = ClientRectangle.Contains(PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
                if (isMouseDown && isLongClicking && !isInClientArea) {
                    longClickTimer.Stop();
                    isLongClicking = false;
                    milliseconds = 0;
                    isLongClick = false;
                } else if (isMouseDown && !isLongClicking && isInClientArea) {
                    isLongClicking = true;
                    startTimer();
                }
            }
            //
            base.OnMouseMove(mevent);
        }

        protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseEnter(e);
            //
            isMouseDown = false;
        }

        protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
        {
            if (mevent.Button.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Left)) {
                longClickTimer.Stop();
                isLongClicking = false;
                milliseconds = 0;

                if (ClientRectangle.Contains(mevent.Location)) {
                    if (isLongClick)
                        LongClick?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
                    else
                        ShortClick?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
                }

                isLongClick = false;
            }
            //
            base.OnMouseUp(mevent);
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pevent);
            //
            float filledArea = bitmap.Height * (float)milliseconds / LongClickTimerTime;
            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)) {
                graphics.Clear(SystemColors.Control);
                graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.ControlDark, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, (int)filledArea));

                var drawingPadding = padding + 2;
                if (ButtonDrawing == EButtonDrawing.Close) {
                    var clientSize = new Size(ClientSize.Width - 1, ClientSize.Height - 1);
                    graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), Point.Add(Point.Empty, new Size(drawingPadding, drawingPadding)), Point.Subtract(new Point(clientSize.Width, clientSize.Height), new Size(drawingPadding * 2, drawingPadding * 2)));
                    graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), Point.Subtract(new Point(0, clientSize.Height), new Size(-drawingPadding, drawingPadding * 2)), Point.Add(new Point(clientSize.Width, 0), new Size(-drawingPadding * 2, drawingPadding)));
                } else if (ButtonDrawing == EButtonDrawing.Settings) {
                    var horStep = (int)((bitmap.Height - padding * 2) / 9);
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        var horY = padding * 2 + (1 + i * 3) * horStep;

                        graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), new Point(padding, horY), new Point(bitmap.Width - padding * 2, horY));
                    }
                } else if (ButtonDrawing == EButtonDrawing.Minimize) {
                    var horStep = (int)((bitmap.Height - padding * 2) / 9);
                    var horY = padding * 2 + (1 + 2 * 3) * horStep;

                    graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), new PointF(padding, horY), new PointF((int)((bitmap.Width - padding * 2) * 0.75f), horY));
                } else if (ButtonDrawing == EButtonDrawing.Add) {
                    var innerPadding = 1;

                    var horYStep = (int)((bitmap.Height - padding * 2f) / 6);
                    var horY = padding * 2 + 2 * horYStep;
                    var newHorY = horY;

                    if (horY % 2 != 1)
                        newHorY -= 1;

                    var verXStep = (int)((bitmap.Width - padding * 2f) / 3);
                    var verX = padding * 2 + 1 * verXStep;
                    var newVerX = verX;

                    if (verX % 2 != 1)
                        newVerX -= 1;

                    graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), new Point(padding + innerPadding, newHorY), new Point((bitmap.Width - padding * 2) - innerPadding, newHorY));

                    graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), new Point(newVerX, padding + innerPadding), new Point(newVerX, (bitmap.Height - padding * 2) - innerPadding));
                }
            }
            pevent.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(bitmap, padding, padding);
        }
    }
}
```